# jQuery active navbuttons + onscroll misbehaving?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My jQuery is misbehaving. What is happening is I just want to get the active menu button correctly displaying once you click and on scroll.

The below code is working a little bit. For example, if I do not click the buttons and just scroll, it highlights the navbar buttons as I scroll. But when I click a button to make it active, it then doesn't work when you scroll. So it appears the click action is disabling the scroll.

EDIT: Something else I forgot to mention. When I scroll to the bottom section the contact, the navbar button for contact doesn't highlight either.

It highlights when I click it but as I said above as soon as I click the buttons it disables the scroll highlighting

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('rjNavActive');
    })
    $(this).addClass('rjNavActive');

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('.rjNav a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('.rjNav a').removeClass("rjNavActive");
      currLink.addClass("rjNavActive");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("rjNavActive");
    }
  });
}

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('.rjNav.shrink a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('.rjNav.shrink a').removeClass("rjNavActive");
      currLink.addClass("rjNavActive");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("rjNavActive");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.rjNavActive {
  background-color: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<a href="#home" class="rjNavActive fa fa-home" data-scroll> Home</a>
<a href="#about" class="fa fa-info" data-scroll> About Me</a>
<a href="#extra" class="fa fa-info" data-scroll> Extra</a>
<a href="#extra2" class="fa fa-picture-o" data-scroll> Extra2</a>
<a href="#extra3" class="fa fa-twitch" data-scroll> Extra3</a>
<a href="#contact" class="fa fa-envelope-o" data-scroll> Contact</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navMob icon" onclick="myFunction()" data-scroll>Logo Name - Menu &#9776;</a>
```

No idea what is causing it to not work correctly!

Comment: Might want to read this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

Comment: @JephrenNaicker - that is irrelevant to my issue, the scroll effect is not the issue in this case.

Comment: Ohk this seem relevant https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: @JephrenNaicker - again, my navbar isn't bootstrap one. So again it is no help, I do not think you understand the issue i am having, I have been clear in my post above.

Comment: Anyone got anymore suggestions?